# Combine 2 array of objects and add null values for non existent properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `marks` array containing objects with `id` and `marks` properties. I also have a `user` array containing objects with `id`, `name`, `grade` & `result` properties.

```js
var marks = [
  { id: '1', marks: 70 },
  { id: '2', marks: 40 },
  { id: '3', marks: 95 },
  { id: '4', marks: 50 },
];

var user = [
  { id: '1', name: 'sam', grade: 1, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '2', name: 'peter', grade: 2, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '5', name: 'John', grade: 1, result: 'Fail' },
  { id: '6', name: 'anna', grade: 3, result: 'Fail' },
];
```

I want to combine the 2 array objects and generate the following result. If a match for id is found,we need to combine the objects else place null for non-existent properties in both the arrays

```js
var result = [
  { id: '1', marks: 70, name: 'sam', grade: 1, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '2', marks: 40, name: 'peter', grade: 2, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '3', marks: 95, name: null, grade: null, result: null },
  { id: '4', marks: 50, name: null, grade: null, result: null },
  { id: '5', marks: null, name: 'John', grade: 1, result: 'Fail' },
  { id: '6', marks: null, name: 'anna', grade: 3, result: 'Fail' },
];
```

I have tried the following piece of code but it doesn't generate the desired result. It generates values based only on the first array

```js
marks.forEach((item) => map.set(item.id, item));
user.forEach((item) => map.set(item.id, { ...map.get(item.id), ...item }));
const mergedArr = Array.from(map.values());
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hint: `...item` does not just magically create the key-value pairs `name: null, grade: null, result: null`

Answer (score 0):

```
var marks = [
  { id: '1', marks: 70 },
  { id: '2', marks: 40 },
  { id: '3', marks: 95 },
  { id: '4', marks: 50 },
];

var users = [
  { id: '1', name: 'sam', grade: 1, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '2', name: 'peter', grade: 2, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '5', name: 'John', grade: 1, result: 'Fail' },
  { id: '6', name: 'anna', grade: 3, result: 'Fail' },
];

type Result = {
    id: string;
    name: string | null;
    grade: number | null;
    result: string | null;
    marks: number | null;
}

const userDefaults = {name: null, grade: null, result: null};
const userMarksDefaults = { marks: null }

// convert the marks array into a map (object) for faster access
const marksAsMap = marks.reduce((accumulator, userMarks) => {
  accumulator[userMarks.id] = userMarks;
  return accumulator;
}, {} as Record<string, typeof marks[number]>);

// convert the users array into a map (object) for faster access
const usersAsMap = users.reduce((accumulator, user) => {
  accumulator[user.id] = user;
  return accumulator;
}, {} as Record<string, typeof users[number]>);

// Grab all ids from both arrays
const uniqueIds = Array.from(new Set([...Object.keys(marksAsMap), ...Object.keys(usersAsMap)]));

const result = uniqueIds.reduce((accumulator, uniqueId) => {
  // default all properties to null and override with actual values
  const user = { ...userDefaults, ...usersAsMap[uniqueId] }
  const userMarks = { ...userMarksDefaults, ...marksAsMap[uniqueId] };
  accumulator.push({
    ...user,
    ...userMarks,
    id: uniqueId,
  });
  return accumulator;
}, [] as Result[])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But am on typescript and it throws error while pushing into accumulator as "Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345) " I tries setting accumulator to type :any={} but it doesn't work. Can you please help with it?

Answer (score 0):

Approach:

- We need the attributes list first which are there in both the items list.
- Construct a sample empty item and overrides if there's a value of it.

If you know the attributes required, you can skip constructing the `attributes` set and hardcode them right there.
The below script dynamically generates the list of attributes present.

```js
// Sample data
const marks = [
  { id: '1', marks: 70 },
  { id: '2', marks: 40 },
  { id: '3', marks: 95 },
  { id: '4', marks: 50 },
];

const users = [
  { id: '1', name: 'sam', grade: 1, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '2', name: 'peter', grade: 2, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '5', name: 'John', grade: 1, result: 'Fail' },
  { id: '6', name: 'anna', grade: 3, result: 'Fail' },
];

// Construct a set of required attributes 
const attributes = new Set();
marks.forEach(mark => Object.keys(mark).forEach(e => attributes.add(e)));
users.forEach(user => Object.keys(user).forEach(e => attributes.add(e)));

// Construct an empty sample object
const sample = {}
attributes.forEach((attribute) => {
    sample[attribute] = null;
})

// Merge all the items with sample object
const mergedItems = {}
marks.forEach(mark => {
    if (mergedItems[mark.id]) {
        mergedItems[mark.id] = {
            ...mergedItems[mark.id],
            ...mark
        };
    } else {
        mergedItems[mark.id] = {
            ...sample,
            ...mark
        };
    }
});
users.forEach(user => {
    if (mergedItems[user.id]) {
        mergedItems[user.id] = {
            ...mergedItems[user.id],
            ...user
        };
    } else {
        mergedItems[user.id] = {
            ...sample,
            ...user
        };
    }
});

// Take out values alone. Don't need keys.
const result = Object.values(mergedItems);

// Print them to console
document.write(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide a reference for you,seems ugly but works(**it will support dynamic properties**)

```js
var marks = [
  { id: '1', marks: 70 },
  { id: '2', marks: 40 },
  { id: '3', marks: 95 },
  { id: '4', marks: 50 },
];

var user = [
  { id: '1', name: 'sam', grade: 1, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '2', name: 'peter', grade: 2, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '5', name: 'John', grade: 1, result: 'Fail' },
  { id: '6', name: 'anna', grade: 3, result: 'Fail' },
];

let keys1 = Object.keys(marks[0]).filter(k => k !== 'id')
let keys2 = Object.keys(user[0]).filter(k => k !== 'id')

let ids = new Set([...marks.map(m => m.id), ...user.map(u => u.id)])
let result = []
for (id of ids) {
   let obj1 = marks.find(i => i.id == id) ?? {}
   let obj2 = user.find(i => i.id == id) ?? {}
   obj = {
      id: id
   }
   for (k1 of keys1) {
      obj[k1] = obj1[k1] ?? null
   }
   for (k2 of keys2) {
      obj[k2] = obj2[k2] ?? null
   }

   result.push(obj)
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to use **map()** to iterate through each object in the marks array and apply a logic to merge and fill in missing properties.

Here, the `map()` iterates over the objects and applies the logic.
The logic is handled by `find()` : it iterates through each element and checks if the ID matches the ID of the object in marks.

And `concat()` combines two or more arrays to create a new array.

*The code filters to find objects that do not have a match, and the second map is used to mark them as null when there is no match in marks*.

```js
var marks = [
  { id: '1', marks: 70 },
  { id: '2', marks: 40 },
  { id: '3', marks: 95 },
  { id: '4', marks: 50 },
];

var user = [
  { id: '1', name: 'sam', grade: 1, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '2', name: 'peter', grade: 2, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '5', name: 'John', grade: 1, result: 'Fail' },
  { id: '6', name: 'anna', grade: 3, result: 'Fail' },
];

var mergedArr = marks.map(mark => {
  const userObj = user.find(userItem => userItem.id === mark.id) || {};
  return {
    id: mark.id,
    marks: mark.marks ?? null,
    name: userObj.name ?? null,
    grade: userObj.grade ?? null,
    result: userObj.result ?? null,
    ...mark,
  };
}).concat(user.filter(userItem => !marks.find(markItem => markItem.id === userItem.id)).map(userItem => ({
  id: userItem.id,
  marks: null,
  name: userItem.name ?? null,
  grade: userItem.grade ?? null,
  result: userItem.result ?? null,
})));

console.log(mergedArr);
```

Comment: it leaves out objects in the user array and null is not popuylated for fields which are absent

Comment: Your result doesn't quite match the requirements. For instance, your last value is  `{"id": "6","name": "anna","grade": 3,"result": "Fail"}` but it should be `{"id":"6","marks":null,"name":"anna","grade":3,"result":"Fail"}`, i.e. it's missing `"marks":null`.

Comment: @sumitra_gangula Would that be the way you need it?

Answer (score 0):

By using `Set` we can determine a unique set of `id` and a unique set of `keys` belonging to both arrays.

```js
const ids = [...new Set([...marks.map(m => m.id), ...user.map(u => u.id)])];
// ids = Array ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

const keys = [...new Set([...Object.keys(marks[0]),...Object.keys(user[0])])];
// keys = Array ["id", "marks", "name", "grade", "result"]
```

We construct a `blank` object which has all the keys but values for nulls.

```js
const blank = keys.reduce((p,c) => { p[c] = null; return p; }, { });
// blank = Object { id: null, marks: null, name: null, grade: null, result: null }
```

Then we use JavaScript spread operator (...) to merge the `blank` object with the corresponding `marks` object and/or `user` object.

```js
 id => ({...blank,
         ...marks.find(m => m.id == id),
         ...user.find(u => u.id == id)})
```

Here's the completed code:

```js
const marks = [
    { id: '1', marks: 70 },
    { id: '2', marks: 40 },
    { id: '3', marks: 95 },
    { id: '4', marks: 50 },
];
const user = [
    { id: '1', name: 'sam', grade: 1, result: 'Pass' },
    { id: '2', name: 'peter', grade: 2, result: 'Pass' },
    { id: '5', name: 'John', grade: 1, result: 'Fail' },
    { id: '6', name: 'anna', grade: 3, result: 'Fail' },
];
const ids = [...new Set([...marks.map(m => m.id), ...user.map(u => u.id)])];
const keys = [...new Set([...Object.keys(marks[0]),...Object.keys(user[0])])];
const blank = keys.reduce((p,c) => { p[c] = null; return p; }, { });
const result = ids.map(id => ({...blank,
                               ...marks.find(m => m.id == id),
                               ...user.find(u => u.id == id)}));
for (let r of result) console.log(JSON.stringify(r));

// Outputs:
// {"id":"1","marks":70,"name":"sam","grade":1,"result":"Pass"}
// {"id":"2","marks":40,"name":"peter","grade":2,"result":"Pass"}
// {"id":"3","marks":95,"name":null,"grade":null,"result":null}
// {"id":"4","marks":50,"name":null,"grade":null,"result":null}
// {"id":"5","marks":null,"name":"John","grade":1,"result":"Fail"}
// {"id":"6","marks":null,"name":"anna","grade":3,"result":"Fail"}
```

There are two issues with the above:

- It assumes that `marks[0]` and `user[0]`, the first entries of the arrays, are representative of entries that follow, so only those records are being scanned to determine the complete list of keys. This assumption is consistent with the data provided by the OP, but is not a generalize solution
- The other issue is the usage of `Array.find()` is, potentially inefficient. This would yield a performance problem if either or both the source arrays are large. Presently, that is not the case with the data provided by the OP, but it is a potential problem

To solve the second issue, we can replace `Array.find()` by generating a hash-lookup object:

```js
const marksLookup = marks.reduce( (p,c) => { p[c.id] = c; return p; }, {});
//  Object { 1: Object { id: "1", marks: 70 },
//           2: Object { id: "2", marks: 40 },
//           3: Object { id: "3", marks: 95 },
//           4: Object { id: "4", marks: 50 } }

const userLookup = user.reduce( (p,c) => { p[c.id] = c; return p; }, {});
//  Object { 1: Object { id: "1", name: "sam", grade: 1, result: "Pass" },
//           2: Object { id: "2", name: "peter", grade: 2, result: "Pass" },
//           5: Object { id: "5", name: "John", grade: 1, result: "Fail" },
//           6: Object { id: "6", name: "anna", grade: 3, result: "Fail" } }
```

Then we can update the JavaScript spread operator (...) to merge the `blank` object with entries from the `marksLookup` object and/or `userLookup` object.

```js
id => ({...blank,
        ...marksLookup[id],
        ...userLookup[id]})
```

Here's a working example of the patch:

```js
const marks = [
    { id: '1', marks: 70 },
    { id: '2', marks: 40 },
    { id: '3', marks: 95 },
    { id: '4', marks: 50 },
];
const user = [
    { id: '1', name: 'sam', grade: 1, result: 'Pass' },
    { id: '2', name: 'peter', grade: 2, result: 'Pass' },
    { id: '5', name: 'John', grade: 1, result: 'Fail' },
    { id: '6', name: 'anna', grade: 3, result: 'Fail' },
];
const marksLookup = marks.reduce( (p,c) => { p[c.id] = c; return p; }, {});
const userLookup = user.reduce( (p,c) => { p[c.id] = c; return p; }, {});
const ids = [...new Set([...marks.map(m => m.id), ...user.map(u => u.id)])];
const keys = [...new Set([...Object.keys(marks[0]),...Object.keys(user[0])])];
const blank = keys.reduce((p,c) => { p[c] = null; return p; }, { });
const result = ids.map(id => ({...blank,
                               ...marksLookup[id],
                               ...userLookup[id]}));
for (let r of result) console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve this in Typescript:

```
const marks = [
    { id: '1', marks: 70 },
    { id: '2', marks: 40 },
    { id: '3', marks: 95 },
    { id: '4', marks: 50 },
  ];
  
  const user = [
    { id: '1', name: 'sam', grade: 1, result: 'Pass' },
    { id: '2', name: 'peter', grade: 2, result: 'Pass' },
    { id: '5', name: 'John', grade: 1, result: 'Fail' },
    { id: '6', name: 'anna', grade: 3, result: 'Fail' },
  ];
  
  type MergedObj = {
    id: string;
    marks: number | null;
    name: string | null;
    grade: number | null;
    result: string | null;
  };
  
  const mergedArr: MergedObj[] = marks.map((mark) => {
    const userObj = user.find((u) => u.id === mark.id);
    return { ...mark, ...(userObj || { name: null, grade: null, result: null }) };
  });
  
  user.forEach((u) => {
    const existingMark = mergedArr.find((mark) => mark.id === u.id);
    if (!existingMark) {
      mergedArr.push({ ...u, marks: null });
    }
  });
  
  console.log(mergedArr);
```

Output will be:

```
[
  { id: '1', marks: 70, name: 'sam', grade: 1, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '2', marks: 40, name: 'peter', grade: 2, result: 'Pass' },
  { id: '3', marks: 95, name: null, grade: null, result: null },
  { id: '4', marks: 50, name: null, grade: null, result: null },
  { id: '5', marks: null, name: 'John', grade: 1, result: 'Fail' },
  { id: '6', marks: null, name: 'anna', grade: 3, result: 'Fail' }
]
```

Answer (score -2):

try this it will help you

```
let data =user.map((user,i)=>{
    let userMarks = marks.find(m=>m.id === user.id);
    return {
        ...user,
        ...userMarks
    }
    
})
console.log("DATA=",data)
```

Comment: This doesn't generate the desired result. `name` and other fields should be `null` if user with corresponding `id` doesn't exist.